# R error Android Studio when rebuilding project

Tags: android, android-studio

I was having an issue with the R symbol in my Android app (it was imported as `import com.myName.runmate.R;` When I removed this lined, I resynched with Gradle and rebuilt the project but I got the following in Messages Gradle Build - `Error:(73, 44) error: package R does not exist`

The logcat output:

```
09-19 13:21:01.969      746-821/? I/PowerManagerService﹕ Going to sleep due to screen timeout (uid 1000)...
09-19 13:21:01.970      746-821/? I/PowerManagerService﹕ Sleeping (uid 1000)...
09-19 13:21:02.078      909-909/? D/PhoneStatusBar﹕ disable: < expand ICONS alerts SYSTEM_INFO back HOME RECENT clock SEARCH >
09-19 13:21:02.104      188-856/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ adev_set_parameters: enter: screen_state=off
09-19 13:21:02.127      746-842/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ cancelDelayedScan -> 2163
09-19 13:21:02.128      746-842/? E/native﹕ do suspend true
09-19 13:21:02.529      746-819/? I/DisplayManagerService﹕ Display device changed: DisplayDeviceInfo{"Built-in Screen": uniqueId="local:0", 1080 x 1920, 60.0 fps, supportedRefreshRates [60.0], density 480, 442.451 x 443.345 dpi, appVsyncOff 7500000, presDeadline 12666667, touch INTERNAL, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, state OFF, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
09-19 13:21:02.529      175-175/? D/SurfaceFlinger﹕ Set power mode=0, type=0 flinger=0xb6482000
09-19 13:21:02.529      175-175/? D/qdhwcomposer﹕ hwc_blank: Blanking display: 0
09-19 13:21:02.530      746-746/? V/ActivityManager﹕ Display changed displayId=0
09-19 13:21:02.813      175-175/? D/qdhwcomposer﹕ hwc_blank: Done blanking display: 0
09-19 13:21:02.813      746-867/? D/SurfaceControl﹕ Excessive delay in setPowerMode(): 284ms
09-19 13:21:02.813    2046-2050/? E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK﹕ Failed to apply optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
09-19 13:21:28.638      746-746/? I/EntropyMixer﹕ Writing entropy...
09-19 13:21:28.640      746-821/? I/PowerManagerService﹕ Waking up from sleep (uid 1000)...
09-19 13:21:28.640      746-821/? I/DisplayPowerController﹕ Blocking screen on until initial contents have been drawn.
09-19 13:21:28.667    1086-1086/? I/PowerConnectionBroadcastReceiver﹕ onReceive() : Device plugged in.
09-19 13:21:28.667    1086-1086/? I/StatsUtilsManager﹕ startPeriodStatsRecorder() : Success
09-19 13:21:28.667    1086-1086/? I/PeriodicStatsRecorder﹕ shouldRecordStats() = Too Soon
09-19 13:21:28.671    8907-8907/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
09-19 13:21:28.671    8907-8907/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
09-19 13:21:28.672    9422-9422/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ Starting service, intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.location.reporting.ACTION_UPDATE_WORLD cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.reporting.service.DispatchingService (has extras) }, extras=Bundle[{receiverAction=android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED}]
09-19 13:21:28.674    9422-9422/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ DispatchingService.onCreate()
09-19 13:21:28.678    9496-9496/? I/iu.Environment﹕ update battery state; isPlugged? true*
09-19 13:21:28.684   9496-12232/? I/iu.UploadsManager﹕ num queued entries: 0
09-19 13:21:28.686   9496-12232/? I/iu.UploadsManager﹕ num updated entries: 0
09-19 13:21:28.688   9496-12232/? I/iu.SyncManager﹕ NEXT; no task
09-19 13:21:28.697   9496-28033/? I/iu.FingerprintManager﹕ Start processing all media
09-19 13:21:28.708   9496-28033/? I/iu.FingerprintManager﹕ Start processing media store URI: content://media/external/images/media
09-19 13:21:28.719    2046-2050/? E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK﹕ Failed to reset optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
09-19 13:21:28.720      746-819/? I/DisplayManagerService﹕ Display device changed: DisplayDeviceInfo{"Built-in Screen": uniqueId="local:0", 1080 x 1920, 60.0 fps, supportedRefreshRates [60.0], density 480, 442.451 x 443.345 dpi, appVsyncOff 7500000, presDeadline 12666667, touch INTERNAL, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, state ON, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
09-19 13:21:28.720      175-175/? D/SurfaceFlinger﹕ Set power mode=2, type=0 flinger=0xb6482000
09-19 13:21:28.720      175-175/? D/qdhwcomposer﹕ hwc_blank: Unblanking display: 0
09-19 13:21:28.769   9496-28033/? I/iu.FingerprintManager﹕ Start processing media store URI: content://media/external/video/media
09-19 13:21:28.775   9496-28033/? I/iu.FingerprintManager﹕ Start processing media store URI: content://media/phoneStorage/images/media
09-19 13:21:28.778   9496-28033/? I/iu.FingerprintManager﹕ Start processing media store URI: content://media/phoneStorage/video/media
09-19 13:21:28.779   9496-28033/? I/iu.FingerprintManager﹕ Finished generating fingerprints; 0.082 seconds
09-19 13:21:28.779   9496-28033/? I/iu.FingerprintManager﹕ numSeen=680 numGenerated=0 numDeleted=0 numFailed=0
09-19 13:21:28.796      746-746/? V/KeyguardServiceDelegate﹕ onScreenTurnedOn(showListener = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager$2@280fe250)
09-19 13:21:28.797      746-746/? V/ActivityManager﹕ Display changed displayId=0
09-19 13:21:28.807  27346-28044/? I/GAv4﹕ Google Analytics 7.8.95 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
    adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
    adb logcat -s GAv4
09-19 13:21:28.812   9422-28036/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ WorldUpdater received intent Intent { act=com.google.android.location.reporting.ACTION_UPDATE_WORLD cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.reporting.service.DispatchingService (has extras) } with receiverAction android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
09-19 13:21:28.823     746-1213/? V/KeyguardServiceDelegate﹕ **** SHOWN CALLED ****
09-19 13:21:28.823      746-821/? I/DisplayPowerController﹕ Unblocked screen on after 183 ms
09-19 13:21:28.829      188-188/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ adev_set_parameters: enter: screen_state=on
09-19 13:21:28.845      746-842/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ cancelDelayedScan -> 2164
09-19 13:21:28.846   1148-25581/? D/BrcmNfcJni﹕ RoutingManager::nfaEeCallback: NFA_EE_SET_TECH_CFG_EVT; status=0x0
09-19 13:21:28.846   1148-25581/? D/BrcmNfcJni﹕ RoutingManager::nfaEeCallback: NFA_EE_SET_PROTO_CFG_EVT; status=0x0
09-19 13:21:28.846    1148-1379/? D/BrcmNfcJni﹕ RoutingManager::commitRouting
09-19 13:21:28.846      746-842/? E/native﹕ do suspend false
09-19 13:21:28.856  27346-28044/? W/GAv4﹕ AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled. Register the receiver for reliable dispatching on non-Google Play devices. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
09-19 13:21:28.856      746-762/? W/ActivityManager﹕ getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10065 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
09-19 13:21:28.865  27346-28044/? W/GAv4﹕ CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
09-19 13:21:28.868   1148-25581/? D/BrcmNfcJni﹕ RoutingManager::nfaEeCallback: NFA_EE_UPDATED_EVT
09-19 13:21:28.871  27346-28055/? W/GAv4﹕ AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be delivered reliably. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
09-19 13:21:28.906      746-761/? I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 28154(1676KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(73KB) LOS objects, 30% free, 36MB/52MB, paused 1.413ms total 89.320ms
09-19 13:21:28.919     746-1252/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc 28057:com.estrongs.android.pop/u0a144 for broadcast com.estrongs.android.pop/.app.StartServiceReceiver
09-19 13:21:28.951  28057-28057/? E/ObjectHelper﹕ Can't find method:setCompatibilityInfo
09-19 13:21:28.959      175-175/? D/qdhwcomposer﹕ hwc_blank: Done unblanking display: 0
09-19 13:21:28.959      746-867/? D/SurfaceControl﹕ Excessive delay in setPowerMode(): 239ms
09-19 13:21:28.976  28057-28077/? D/an﹕ Refresh storage info done.21
09-19 13:21:28.982   9422-28036/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ WorldUpdater:android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED: Ensuring that reporting is stopped because of reasons: {account#-19#=[InactiveReason{mVersionCode=0, mIdentifier=6, mName='ReportingNotEnabled'}]}
09-19 13:21:28.985   9422-28036/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ Unbound from all location providers
09-19 13:21:28.996    9422-9422/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ DispatchingService.onDestroy()
09-19 13:21:28.996    9422-9422/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ Stopping handler for UlrDispSvcFast
09-19 13:21:28.999    9422-9422/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ Unbound from all location providers
09-19 13:21:29.038  28057-28079/? W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
09-19 13:21:29.453    746-17030/? D/AlarmManagerService﹕ Kernel timezone updated to -60 minutes west of GMT
09-19 13:21:29.460  27491-27491/? D/CellBroadcastReceiver﹕ onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE flg=0x10 cmp=com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver/.CellBroadcastReceiver (has extras) }
09-19 13:21:29.460  27491-27491/? D/CellBroadcastReceiver﹕ Intent ACTION_SERVICE_STATE_CHANGED
09-19 13:21:29.460  27491-27491/? D/CellBroadcastReceiver﹕ Service state changed! 0 Full: 0 0 voice home data home O2 - UK O2 - UK 23410 O2 - UK O2 - UK 23410  UMTS HSPAP CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1 DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false Current state=-1
09-19 13:21:29.464      746-844/? D/ConnectivityService﹕ rematching NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (HSPA) - 127]
09-19 13:21:29.464      746-844/? D/ConnectivityService﹕ Network NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (HSPA) - 127] was already satisfying request 1. No change.
09-19 13:21:29.464      746-844/? D/ConnectivityService﹕ notifyType AVAILABLE for NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (HSPA) - 127]
09-19 13:21:29.465      746-844/? D/ConnectivityService﹕ notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (HSPA) - 127]
09-19 13:21:29.466      746-844/? D/ConnectivityService﹕ Setting tx/rx TCP buffers to 122334,734003,2202010,32040,192239,576717
09-19 13:21:29.468   9496-27601/? D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler﹕ CM callback handler got msg 524290
09-19 13:21:29.469     909-1321/? D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler﹕ CM callback handler got msg 524290
09-19 13:21:29.470     909-1321/? D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler﹕ CM callback handler got msg 524294
09-19 13:21:29.470   9496-27601/? D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler﹕ CM callback handler got msg 524294
09-19 13:21:29.472      746-746/? I/ValidateNoPeople﹕ skipping global notification
09-19 13:21:29.473      746-746/? V/NotificationService﹕ pkg=android canInterrupt=false intercept=true
09-19 13:21:29.485      746-746/? I/ValidateNoPeople﹕ skipping global notification
09-19 13:21:29.485      746-746/? V/NotificationService﹕ pkg=android canInterrupt=false intercept=true
09-19 13:21:29.496      746-844/? D/ConnectivityService﹕ notifyType IP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (HSPA+) - 127]
09-19 13:21:29.500     909-1321/? D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler﹕ CM callback handler got msg 524295
09-19 13:21:29.501   9496-27601/? D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler﹕ CM callback handler got msg 524295
09-19 13:21:29.505  27491-28097/? D/CellBroadcastConfigService﹕ enabling emergency cell broadcast channels
09-19 13:21:29.510   1220-19744/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] enableGsmBroadcastRange
09-19 13:21:29.510   1220-19744/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Added GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4352 to 4354 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
09-19 13:21:29.510   1220-19744/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Calling setCellBroadcastActivation(true)
09-19 13:21:29.523    1220-5492/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] enableGsmBroadcastRange
09-19 13:21:29.524    1220-5492/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Added GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4356 to 4356 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
09-19 13:21:29.524    1220-5492/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Calling setCellBroadcastActivation(true)
09-19 13:21:29.531    1220-1241/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] enableGsmBroadcastRange
09-19 13:21:29.532    1220-1241/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Added GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4371 to 4372 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
09-19 13:21:29.532    1220-1241/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Calling setCellBroadcastActivation(true)
09-19 13:21:29.547    1220-5172/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] enableCdmaBroadcastRange
09-19 13:21:29.547    1220-5172/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Calling setCdmaBroadcastConfig with 1 configurations
09-19 13:21:29.551    1220-5172/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to add cdma broadcast subscription for MID range 4097 to 4097 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
09-19 13:21:29.560   1220-29365/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] enableGsmBroadcastRange
09-19 13:21:29.560   1220-29365/? D/IccSmsInterfaceManager﹕ [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Added GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4373 to 4378 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
```

Comment: It was in Messages Gradle Build - I will add it now

Comment: Question updated, I had to remove some lines from the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the Lines Where your Getting Error With R in Java File

Then Build the project

It Should Rebuild the R file Again

Now Remove Your Comments and You are good to go

Comment: I have quite a few lines to comment and then uncomment... Is this the quickest approach?

Comment: Thanks a lot@rajan ks,was banging my head for that,always it happens when i try to clean project

Answer (score 0):

Can you ensure all your package names are the same:

```
package com.khackett.runmate;
```

Not adding the folder extension for each folder the files are in.

```
package com.khackett.runmate.adapters;
```

As you have declared in your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.khackett.runmate" >
```

Comment: I changed all of the package names, then I had to change the imports names to match... I eventually got the app to run (even though there was an error in each of the classes where the package name did not have an extension)... it built ok, but the tabs where missing and the same `getListView()` error occurred as in the original question when I swiped between the tabs. I may just have to revert to what I had originally.

Comment: thanks for all of the help... I have a deadline with this project this week so I couldn't afford any more time to correct this bug.  I got a workaround in the mean time though - I removed the friendsfragment which contained a gridview in one of the tabs and this seemed to have fixed it.